# How can I make two things happen at the same time?

Tags: python, python-3.8

Here's my code:

```py
while True:
    print("Hi")

print("Whatsup")
```

It doesn't print Whatsup. So, how can I make it print Whatsup and do the loop at the same time?

Comment: `while True` is an infinite loop. It will run forever unless you make it stop by passing some condition. Hence, `Whatsup` is never printed.

Comment: What do you mean "at the same time"?

Comment: If I were to run the loop, it doesn't print. How can I make it so I can run some stuff after the loop without ending the loop?

Comment: You would use multiprocessing, multithreading, or something like asyncio. Which you'd use though depends entirely on what exactly the loop and the other code are doing.

Comment: As others said, it appears that you'll need multithreading or multiprocessing, otherwise your code will run serially. meaning that `Whatsup` will be printed "after" your `while True` loop, which is never. Look for some python multithreading/multiprocessing tutorial in YouTube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While loop is in infinite loop which can never escape. Thread method can be implemeted for parallel process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("Whatsup")
while True:
    print("Hi")
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got to break the loop here

```
while True:
    print('Hi')
    if ( 1 == 1):
         break
print('Whatsapp!')
```

Comment: why `if (1 == 1)`? you can use `if True`, just like `while True`.. Anyway, there is no essence in doing something in a loop if you anyway break it after the first iteration

Comment: Honestly, I don't see the purpose of this question. I thought he wants to print Hi first in a while loop and then print Whatsup.

Comment: there r no need to do while and if since the loop break after the first iteration ,it's juste like print('hi') then print('whatsapp!')

Comment: @astroboy1, definitely, the question is not asked well, probably thanks to lack of basic knowledge